# Accessing ListViews, RecycleViews, LinearLayouts in different paths

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-recyclerview

I have been reading for solutions for a while but this looks ambiguous to me. I am trying to access elements like `ListViews`,`RecycleViews` etc. I have a file called Main.axml in my Layout structure. Main.axml belongs to `Activity1`.

But now, i am trying to refer to the `recycleView` in the layout structure, but i get an exception `(systemNullReference)`. My question seems a bit weird but if i cannot reach the `recycleView` in the Main.axml, why wouldn't the ide in the first place throw an error before i deploy onto my phone?  Below is how i am trying to access the id of the `recycleview` in Main.axml?

**Activity2.cs**

```
private RecycleView recycleView;

 //trying to access id in Main.axml
recycleView = FindViewById<RecycleView>(Resource.Layout.recyleView1);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have

```
recycleView = FindViewById<RecycleView>(Resource.Layout.recyleView1);
```

and it should be:

```
recycleView = FindViewById<RecycleView>(Resource.Id.recyleView1);
```

Note:

Your **Main.axml** layout file must contain a `RecycleView` with Id **recyleView1**.

Comment: I am still getting the same error null. My Main.Axml has a recycleview with the id **recycleView1**.. I am accessing this id in an activity which is not doesn't set a content view of Main.axml but rather a different axml file

Comment: You can't do that and that's not a Xamarin thing but this is how Android works. You can only access objects of the Layout (axml) file you set as your ContentView in an Activity.